# Cut an 2d Array down to needed part

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with some numbers in it, that are procedurally generated through the Code and I want to remove the part of the array that is not necessary.

So until now I tried my best to create my own code, but it didn't work quite well (Thats the reason why im here).

This was my try:

```
private void cutPlacementMap() {
    int firstNeededX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int firstNeededZ = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int lastNeededX = -1;
    int lastNeededZ = -1;

    for (int x = 0; x < placementMap.length; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < placementMap[0].length; z++) {
            if (placementMap[x][z] != 0) {
                if (x < firstNeededX)
                    firstNeededX = x;

                if (z < firstNeededZ)
                    firstNeededZ = z;

                if (x > lastNeededX)
                    lastNeededX = x;

                if (z > lastNeededZ)
                    lastNeededZ = z;
            }
        }
    }

    int lengthX = lastNeededX - firstNeededX;
    int lengthZ = lastNeededZ - firstNeededZ;
    int[][] newPlacementMap = new int[lengthX + 1][lengthZ + 1];

    System.out.println("lengthX: " + lengthX);
    System.out.println("lengthZ: " + lengthZ);
    int conX = 0;
    int conZ = 0;

    for (int x = firstNeededX; x <= lastNeededX; x++) {
        for (int z = firstNeededZ; x <= lastNeededZ; z++) {
            newPlacementMap[conX][conZ] = placementMap[x][z];
            conZ++;
        }
        conZ = 0;
        conX++;
    }

    placementMap = newPlacementMap;

}
```

This Code throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. That is pointing to the line `newPlacementMap[conX][conZ] = placementMap[x][z];` as reason for the exception.

Every help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging this yourself should be pretty easy.

Take a look at your loop:

```
for (int z = firstNeededZ; x <= lastNeededZ; z++)
```

This will loop forever (or until you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`), because your stop condition contains a typo.

`x <= lastNeededZ` must of course be `z <= lastNeededZ`.

Comment: Good catch! Should his `newPlacementMap` variables have their bounds changed as well, or are they correct as-is?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja I think they are indeed incorrect. The +1 is not needed. But making them too large would not cause the exception. Besides, easiest way to check those things is to fire up the debugger ;-)

Comment: Actually, looking back over it, I think they are intentionally made that size, since (for example) if only one element in the X direction is needed, then `firstNeededX == lastNeededX`, so `lengthX == 0`, which would otherwise result in a 0xZ container when a 1xZ container is needed. The problem comes around in the fact that the lengths should have that +1 added when they are declared, since otherwise the printed value doesn't match the true size of the container.